# C# Simple console application displaying/logical issue

Tags: c#, list, console, console-application, text-based

```
        List<int> numberList = new List<int>();
        List<int> uniqueList = new List<int>();

        string input;
        int number = 0;
        bool over = false;

        while (!over)
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "quit")
            {
                over = true;
                break;
            }
            if (int.TryParse(input, out number))
            {
                numberList.Add(number);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!uniqueList.Contains(number))
            {
                uniqueList.Add(number);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < uniqueList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(uniqueList[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Hi! I need some help with this program that takes in numbers, but upon typing "quit", it should list all the **unique** numbers that have been entered.

For example here's the input: **5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 1, 3**
The console should only display **1** and **3** because they are the only **unique** numbers.

The problem is, that the program in its current form only displays the last unique number that has been entered, not all of them and I don't know why.

Could you tell me why? What do I need to do to list all of them?

Comment: When you debugged through it, what did the code do that you expected it not to do?

Comment: Your code simply ignores duplicates, it does not keep the numbers referenced only one. To do that: `numberList.GroupBy(number => number).Where(group => (group.Count() == 1)).Select(group => group.Key)`. Also, using `Contains` with a list is very inefficient. You could use a `Dictionary<int, int>` to store the numbers along with their number of occurences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a Dictionary to record the count of each number, then return the unique ones:

```
    Dictionary<int, int> numberDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    string input;
    int number = 0;
    bool over = false;

    while (!over)
    {
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input == "quit")
        {
            over = true;
            break;
        }
        if (int.TryParse(input, out number))
        {
            if (numberDictionary.TryGetValue(number), out int count)
            {
                numberDictionary[number] = count + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                numberDictionary.Add(number, 1);
            } 
        }
    }

    foreach(var item in numberDictionary)
    {
        if (item.Value == 1)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Remove the numberDictionary double lookup and you'll get my vote.

Comment: Thank you, this is my favorite answer. The answer above yours is working too, I just don't know LINQ yet, but I used Dictionary once in a Unity course. So this is more understandable for me.

Comment: Now you can have it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this much simpler

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>{1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6};
var unique = numbers.Where(n => numbers.Count(m => m == n) == 1);
foreach(var u in unique)
    WriteLine(u);
```

Prints

> 1
>
> 5

What this is doing is it is takign the List numbers, and it Where looks at each member in the list (in this case that member is called `n`).

It then checks if the number of occurences of `n` is equal to 1. If it is this must be unique.

So for the first number in our list 1, the following:

`numbers.Count(m => m == n)`

Will return 1.

When `n` is 2 then

`numbers.Count(m => m == n)`

Will return 2.

Comment: Thank you it worked, although I don't understand the LINQ part.

Comment: This code executes n*n comparisons which might present a perf issue if the list grows

Answer (score 1):

This is a full implementation of the solution :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace EntryPoint.Concole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           List<int> numberList = new List<int>();
           List<int> uniqueList = new List<int>();

           string input;
           int number = 0;
           bool over = false;

           while (!over)
           {
               input = Console.ReadLine();
               if (input == "quit")
               {
                  over = true;
                  break;
               }
               if (int.TryParse(input, out number))
               {
                  numberList.Add(number);
               }
           }

           var numbersDistinct = numberList.GroupBy(i => i);

           foreach (var num in numbersDistinct)
           {
              if (num.Count() == 1)
              {
                  uniqueList.Add(num.Key);
              }
           }

           for (int i = 0; i < uniqueList.Count; i++)
           {
              Console.WriteLine(uniqueList[i]);
           }

           Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and fixed your code. Although it is not perfect but I have pointed out the crucial mistakes.

```
        List<int> numberList = new List<int>();
        List<int> uniqueList = new List<int>();

        string input;
        int number = 0;
        bool over = false;

        while (!over)
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "quit")
            {
                over = true;
                //break; // it is not needed since you have over = true
            }
            if (int.TryParse(input, out number))
            {
                numberList.Add(number);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberList.Count; i++)
        {
            //if (!uniqueList.Contains(number)) // this is the wrong line
            if (numberList.Count(q => q == numberList[i]) == 1)
            {
                //uniqueList.Add(number); // this is also wrong
                uniqueList.Add(numberList[i]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < uniqueList.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(uniqueList[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

In simple words the Count(...) method in the

numberList.Count(q => q == numberList[i]) == 1

line just counts elements of the numberList which satisfy provided condition. In this case, condition is 
q == numberList[i]
which basically means to count elements that equal to numberList[i].

You may also read about delegates and lambda expressions in C# for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to remove "break". Could explain the LINQ line? I haven't used them before and I'd like to understand it.